# What's wrong with my JQuery syntax here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

This code is throwing me a syntax error:

```
$("body").live("click", (function(){ 
        if ((! mouse_is_inside) && ($("div#notification_box").is(":visible"))) {
           $("div#notification_box").hide();
           $("p.exclamation").removeClass("exclamation_hover");
           $.ajax("/videos/update_box.js");
      }     
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `(` before `function`.  You have mismatched parentheses.

Comment: +1 @user: You only need to put parens around a function expression when *you're* about to call that function, e.g.: `(function() { ... })()` (note the parens around the expression, and separately the parens at the end, calling the function immediately after defining it). When you're just using a function expression as a right-hand value (as you are there, passing it into the `live` function), no need to wrap `function` in parens. (And of course, your parens have to be matched.)

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `(` right before `function(){`

Here is the proper code:

```
$("body").live("click", function(){ 
    if ((! mouse_is_inside) && ($("div#notification_box").is(":visible"))) {
       $("div#notification_box").hide();
       $("p.exclamation").removeClass("exclamation_hover");
       $.ajax("/videos/update_box.js");
  }     
});
```